# STL sorting in nested data structure

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, nested, structure

this is STL based data structure that I created for representing graph in C++.

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> ii;
typedef std::vector<ii> vii;
typedef std::vector< vii > graph;
```

in Kruskal algorithm that I read in Steven Halim's (Competitive programming) book he uses the vector of edges.

```
vector< pair<int, pair<int,int> > > edges;
```

then he sorts is by weight (the first **int** in pair). I implemented this algorithm and it worked, but I want to use the previous data structure and I don't know how to sort edges by weight because it has the nested structure.

`vector< vector< pair < int, int> > > graph` - **how to sort this graph by the second parameters in pair that represents the weight ?**

```
std::sort( mygraph.begin(), mygraph.end(), /* HERE I GOT A TROUBLE */ )
```

Thank you

Comment: Replace `/* HERE I GOT A TROUBLE */` with an appropriate lambda function to compare the weights.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort has plenty of examples on how to use std::sort

Comment: When someone throws `vector<vector<pair<int, int> > >` at me and tells me "it's a graph", I have some trouble understanding how the graph would be constructed from this. I feel like you would need to sort the inner vectors, but then again I have no idea what which vector is representing in your model. Care to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just cannot sort the graph the way you want using `std::sort()`.

If I understand correctly, `mygraph[u]` contains `{v,w}` pairs such that there is an edge from `u` to `v` of weight `w`. You want to sort the edge list by weight for Kruskal. But you simply cannot do this with the structure proposed!

`std::sort()` on `mygraph` will reorder the rows of your adjacency list without ordering the edges within a row. And there is no natural way to order the rows themselves because the smallest edges might be in different rows.

For example, consider two rows of the vector like this:

```
mygraph[0] = {{1,1}, {3,3}}
mygraph[1] = {{2,2}}
```

Now you want the `{2,2}` edge to come between the other two edges in sorted order but this is impossible if you just sort the vector.

You are hence forced to flatten the vector so that you have a 1D vector of edges (of the form `{w,{u,v}}` the way Halim has) which you can sort.

Comment: Thank you. I created a function that reads the first data structure and converts it to the list of edges

Comment: @SuleymanSuleyman-zade, Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.